# Find sum of prime numbers less than 100

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm attempting to write a method within a class that finds the sum of prime numbers. This is what I have so far:

```
class Primes

    require 'rspec'
    require 'prime'

    def self_sum_to num
    Prime.each(num).inject(&:+)
    end

end

Primes.self_sum_to 100
```

The error I get is:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file — rspec
method require  in kernel_require.rb at line 55
method require  in kernel_require.rb at line 55
method <class:Primes>   in primes.rb at line 3
method <main>   in primes.rb at line 1'
```

If I remove `'require rspec'`, I get the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method ‘self_sum_to’ for Primes:Class
method <main>   in primes.rb at line 11
```

I'm not sure why I am getting this error because the method self.sum_to has been declared.

Any help with this will be much appreciated.

Comment: _"self.sum_to has been declared"_ – you seem to be aware of the correct syntax, so I'm voting to close this as _"caused by a simple typographical error"_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `def self_sum_to` to `def self.sum_to`.

`self_sum_to` is just an ordinary method, whereas `self.sum_to` defines method for the entire class.

```
require 'prime'

class Primes
  def self.sum_to(num)
    Prime.each(num).inject(&:+)
  end
end

Primes.sum_to 100
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew I was close. This has fixed the error, but when I call the method at the end I'm not getting any output to the console. Why is that?

Comment: @sledge_909 probably because you don't output anything. Try `puts Primes.sum_to(100)`

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Been going around in circles so much that I missed the simple stuff.

Answer (score -1):

public class SumOfNPrmNos_2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 10; i < 30; i++) {
        char check = 'T';
        for (int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                check = 'F';
                break;
            }
        }
        if (check == 'T') {
            sum = sum + i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sum Is : = " + sum);

}
```

}